# unhandled element <metadata/>; Picture key: Svg loader Flutter

Tags: flutter, svg

I want to use Svg as a custom icon for my flutter app and I used [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) package for this but it gives this error.

Yes, I upload svg in assets folder and also mention it in Pubspec.yaml

```
  assets:
    - assets/icons/
```

I have implement like this:

```
SvgPicture.asset(
                      'assets/icons/vs.svg',
                      height: 30,
                      width: 30,
                    ),
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

try adding the file name to **pubsec.yaml** like below :
**assets:**
**- assets/icons/vs.svg**

or try adding in the child or children of widget

Comment: I tried it already but still it gives an error.

Comment: use can use different svg file and try checking if error continues or not. if yes then try by removing metadata element from svg file by editing it.